# Can I use SpotifyCharts for getting music album, artists and song names for US using Spotify API for commercial use?

Tags: music

I want to create a music application for which I need to support user searching for top music albums, artists or songs in USA using voice. In order to create language model I need to cache these charts entries...not actually the song content.

I am building it for a client so it's a commercial application. Can I get those charts using spotify API for free? They seem to allow you to download them for free here 
https://spotifycharts.com/regional/us/weekly/latest

So I wonder may be it's also allowed to scrape it or get the charts using API.